# Unable to show all content of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel which is by default showing only 3 lines of text. I want to display all text content in some cases. I have tried everything I found, but nothing works. Here is my latest try:

```
CGRect labelSize = [contents.contentLanguage.Description boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.97, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]} context:nil];

        cell.descLbl.frame = CGRectMake(labelSize.origin.x,
                                                 labelSize.origin.y,
                                                 ceil(labelSize.size.width),
                                                 ceil(labelSize.size.height));

        [cell.descLbl setNumberOfLines:0];
        [cell.descLbl setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [cell.descLbl sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at maybe using the UITextView instead? It's much better suited for multiline text.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview

Comment: I can't, I removed UITextView because it created problems with the scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to resolve this issue by changing the height of the UILabel from the .xib file to >=0

Comment: actually, the reason you couldn't see all the content of UILabel because of the height Constraint, what you have done is changed the relation of the NSLayoutConstraint to satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways (choices) to do it:

1. Use UITextView without editing permission
2. Use UILabel with numberOfLines = 0

**Use UITextView without editing permission**

 If you've fixed space (limited area to display your content i.e. fixed height) to diplay your content and you can't work with scrollable content then you should use UITextView without editing permission.

[image]

**Use UILabel with numberOfLines = 0**

 If you've flexible space (no limited space/area to display a your content i.e. fixed height) to display your content, then you should use UILabel with number of line = 0.

- Do not assign height value (constraint) if you want a flexible UILabel with height, that fits according to size of your content.
- Or Assign minimum height value (constraint like >= 30) if you want to have/set a minimum area for content, whether there is no content to be display.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use UiTextView in place of UILabel

```
textviewobj.text=@"";

[textviewobj sizeToFit];
```